# Wishlist system with Laravel and Spatie query builder

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I need to create a wishlist with laravel, I already use spatie/query-builder to get products.
At this time everything works fine and I can retrieve products already added to wishlist.
I need help for reverse the process.

Three tables are used :

- **users**
- **products**
- **products_favorites** (pivot table) with user_id and product_id

If record exists in pivot table product is in wishlist

So with this custom query builder filter :

```php
return $query->join('product_favorites', function ($query) {
    $query->on('product_favorites.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
})->where('product_favorites.user_id', '=', Auth::id());
```

I can get products who are in current user wishlist. I want to reverse the process.
Get all products who aren't in **product_favorites** table.

How do you think I can achieve this ?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this on seems to work :

```php
return $query->leftJoin('product_favorites', function ($query) {
    $query->on('product_favorites.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
})->where('product_favorites.user_id', '=', null);
```